# Class 'App\Controllers\Users\PHPExcel_Style_Alignment' not found in CodeIgniter: 4.2.6

Tags: codeigniter-4

[image]

PHPExcel_Style_Alignment is not working in the CodeIgniter: 4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following under the Namespace declaration within your controller Attendance.php.

`use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\PHPExcel_Style_Alignment;`